# In drupal 7 I want to crop same image for different device ratios. How can I do this?

Tags: media, theming

In drupal 7 I want to crop same image for different  device ratios. How can I do this.

On uploading image and We have to crop for different ratios.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [picture module](https://www.drupal.org/project/picture) combined with [breakpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/breakpoints) module. Worked perfect for me.